# Create Gtk3 Treeview with CellRendererToggle and Names from List with Python

Tags: python, gtk3

I try to create a Gtk.TreeView with header names from a list. Because I want to use it to show entries from different databases later.

The problem:
When I click on a cell and try to activate it all cells in the row getting activated. More strange, they look not activated, only if I move the cursor over them (not clicking).

What is the problem with this code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk


class CellRendererToggleWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="CellRendererToggle Example")
        self.set_default_size(400, 200)
        self.mainbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing = 10)
        self.add(self.mainbox)

        self.myliststore = Gtk.ListStore(bool,bool,str)
        self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView(self.myliststore)

        for n, header_text in enumerate(["Aktive", "Warning", "Text"]):
            if header_text in ["Aktive", "Warning"]:
                cell = Gtk.CellRendererToggle()
                cell.connect("toggled", self.on_sync_treeview_button_toggled, n, header_text )
                column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(header_text, cell)
            else:
                cell = Gtk.CellRendererText()
                cell.set_property('editable', True)
                column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(header_text, cell, text=n)
            column.set_sort_column_id(n)
            self.treeview.append_column(column)
        self.myliststore.append([True, True, "Super6!"])
        self.myliststore.append([True, True, "Super7!"])
        self.myliststore.append([True, True, "Super8!"])
        self.mainbox.pack_start(self.treeview, True, True, 0)

    def on_sync_treeview_button_toggled(self, widget, path, column, data):
        widget.set_active( [True,False][widget.get_active()] )


win = CellRendererToggleWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TreeViewColumn needs an attribute for "active" with the position in the store:

```
column.add_attribute(cell, "active", n)
```

And I also had to change the underlying store and not the widget:

```
self.myliststore[path][column] = not self.myliststore[path][column]
```

Thanks for this example:
https://github.com/Programmica/python-gtk3-tutorial/blob/master/_examples/cellrenderertoggle.py

Now it is working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk


class CellRendererToggleWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="CellRendererToggle Example")
        self.set_default_size(400, 200)
        self.mainbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing = 10)
        self.add(self.mainbox)

        self.myliststore = Gtk.ListStore(bool,bool,str)
        self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView(self.myliststore)

        for n, header_text in enumerate(["Aktive", "Warning", "Text"]):
            if header_text in ["Aktive", "Warning"]:
                cell = Gtk.CellRendererToggle()
                cell.connect("toggled", self.on_sync_treeview_button_toggled, n, header_text )
                column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(header_text, cell)
                column.add_attribute(cell, "active", n)

            else:
                cell = Gtk.CellRendererText()
                cell.set_property('editable', True)
                column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(header_text, cell, text=n)
            column.set_sort_column_id(n)
            self.treeview.append_column(column)
        self.myliststore.append([True, False, "Super6!"])
        self.myliststore.append([True, True, "Super7!"])
        self.myliststore.append([False, True, "Super8!"])
        self.mainbox.pack_start(self.treeview, True, True, 0)

    def on_sync_treeview_button_toggled(self, widget, path, column, data):
        self.myliststore[path][column] = not self.myliststore[path][column]


win = CellRendererToggleWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept of 'selecting a cell' is not really implemented in a `GtkTreeView`. If you look over all the functions available for TreeView, very few of them really addresses single cells.

That leaves you with these options:

1. Implement your own 'single cell' highlighting (such as adding a border or changing the background color, eg. by adding extra columns which change the properties of the cells.
2. Using a `Gtk.Grid`, where the 'granularity' is one cell, but which does not have the niceties of column headers, and a nice model to load the data into.
3. Another solution to highlight a cell (the row is already highlighted), is to change the color (or other property) of the corresponding column header.

None of the options is really attractive, and each method requires some work.